# Basic mechanics, motion in one dimension

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

I've just started to read Physics by Serway et al. In the problems section in chapter 2 there's the following question:

> The driver of a car slams on the brakes when he sees a tree blocking the road. The car slows uniformly with an acceleration of -25,60 m/$s^2$ for 4,20 s, making straight skid marks 62,4 m long, all the way to the tree. With what speed does the car then strike the tree?

I've assumed constant acceleration, and I let $x_i=0$ at $t=0$. I get the answer to be -38,9 m/s (see below), so the car never slams the tree. The answer in the book is 3,10 m/s. Who is right me or the book. If I'm wrong what did I do wrong?
$$a=-25,60\,m/s^2$$
$$t=4,20\,s$$
$$x_f=62,4\,m$$
$$v_f=v_i+at\tag{1}$$
$$x_f=x_i+v_it+\frac{at^2}{2}\tag{2}$$
Solve (1) for $v_i$, where $x_i=0$:
$$v_i=\frac{2x_f-at^2}{2t}\tag{3}$$
Substitute (3) into (1) gives:
$$v_f=\frac{2x_f-at^2}{2t}+at\tag{4}$$
Plugging in the numerical values above gives me the answer $v_f\approx-38,9\,m/s$ the answer in the book is 3,10 m/s.

Comment: What's wrong with this question? I clearly showed the readers how I thought about the problem and just didn't ask for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:  [Courtesy of Google books](https://books.google.com/books?id=wQCMC3ryYzkC&q=skid#v=snippet&q=skid&f=false), the acceleration for this problem is much less than what you give in your post (perhaps you have a different edition?):

[image]

I'll leave what I wrote earlier for whatever it's worth.

---

Why not reason this out for yourself?  You *know* that the change in velocity over the given time interval is

$$\Delta v = -25.6\,\mathrm{\frac{m}{s^2}}\cdot 4.2\,\mbox{s} = -107.52\,\mathrm{\frac{m}{s}}$$

and so the initial velocity must be greater than this if the car is to hit the tree with non-zero speed.  So, try the edge case (the car stops just at the tree) by setting the initial velocity to $107.52\,\mathrm{\frac{m}{s}}$ and solve for resulting distance traveled. What can you deduce from the result?

Comment: Thank you! In my edition a = -25,6 m/s^2, so it must be an error in the book. Plugging in a= -5,60 m/s^2 yields the right result.